# L2 norm works better than Hamming for ORB in the BoW model, why?

Tags: opencv, classification, knn, orb

I've read in numerous papers that Hamming distance needs to be used when dealing with feature matching using ORB features. I have been playing around with the BoW model in opencv in C++ and find that I have been getting better classification accuracy if I use the default BruteForce matcher (which uses L2) when compared to using BruteForce matcher(Hamming or Hamming(2)).

Why is this?

I was under the impression that you can't use L2 norm but it is providing better classification accuracy than using the hamming distance.

Comment: I'm not sure there is really a difference between the two norms for binary vectors, except for the square root in L2. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I've kept reading that binary descriptors need to be compared using a Hamming distance. Still not sure what method is correct =S

Comment: Binary descriptors are indeed compared using hamming distance, but I'm not sure if it matters for clustering. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have two 3-bit ORB-Descriptors:

```
A = [101]
B = [011]
```

The hamming distance is the number of positions at which the corresponding characters are different:

```
hamming = 2
```

The L2 distance is the euclidean distance:

```
L2 = sqrt(2)
```

For a binary descriptor like ORB, you usually take the hamming distance, because it has a higher efficiency